# Heroku Postgres backup frozen - button just displaying "Capturing", never finishes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, backup

Heroku Postgres backup frozen - button just displaying "Capturing", never finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue myself. Run `heroku pg:backups --app sushi` to see status of backup. I don't remember it correctly but deleting the running backup helps I guess.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#checking-backup-status